# Is a weather resistant gfci required outside in a metal box with in use cover?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, conduit

I have a pool that is just off my deck. The gfci I have went bad so I need a new one. It was a 15 amp gfci in a metal box attached to 1/2 in emt conduit with a metal box and a non in-use cover. This is just under the lip of the deck, so it is slightly protected from weather but not completely. I plan on replacing the box and also getting a in-use cover mainly because the screw holes are stripped out. My question is: Do I need a Weather Resistant GFCI vs a Non Weather resistant GFCI? The current one was not weather resistant and went bad, it tripped and won't reset. Also if someone can explain what the difference is between a standard gfci and weather resistant? Is the weather resistant more sealed to handle more dampness from being outside? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WR GFI uses stainless components and screws. GFI's are notorious for rusting, especially at the mounting screws. The one that went bad was probably older, before WR's were even available.

Yes, you need a WR GFI, and an in-use cover. In fact, I'd venture to bet that much of your installation is not up to code. IF it is that close to the pool the receptacle and plug must be of the locking type (twist-lock), and the circuit protected by an upstream GFI. The outside portion of the wiring to a pool motor must also be in conduit with individual insulated conductors. Older codes would allow this installation located between 5-10 feet from the pool, but NO closer than 5'. Also, the cord on the motor should be no longer than 3' and must be #12 or larger.

There are MANY codes involved with pool installations, I hope yours meets them.

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely required in any outside branch circuit. It must also be installed in a weather proof box.

Comment: Just keep in mind that it's also possible to put the GFCI upstream of the outside outlet, in a more benign location :)